# Javascript hide/show div on passed term

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

Either 'y' or 'n' is passed into my javascript. I need to show a div within my HTML if 'y' is passed, and hide it if 'n'. I currently have this beneath.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(category = 'y'){
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mydiv");
            x.style.display = 'block';
    }else
            x.style.display = 'none';

</script>
<html>
<div class="mydiv">
  <p><h1>Weather</h1></p>
</div>

</html>
```

The div is always being displayed and the term is being ignored, where am I going wrong? Thanks

Comment: Should be 2 `==` (or 3 `===`) in `category = 'y'` for comparison

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns collection. Use `x[0].style.display = 'block';`

Comment: Also missing `{` at the end of `else{` and you haven't close the else condition `}` and your selector will return a group/collection of elements. `x` will only be defined if your condition is true.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined is an error I recieve

Comment: @NewToJS, that's actually fine. If you have only 1 line of code, you do not need to enclose it in brackets.

Comment: @doutriforce still dirty.  Be consistent with brackets.

Comment: @AndrewIce, i know. I was just saying that it's not _really_ necessary. It wouldn't give you an error.

Comment: @doutriforce the rest is relevant though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your if statement should be `if(category == 'y')`
When using only one = sign you are telling the interpreter to assign the value 'y' to variable name `category`

Second,`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements so you need to select an element from the resulting collection for example:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mydiv")[0];
```

Notice how I chose the first element from the array.
Here is the complete code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mydiv")[0]; // should be outside of the if statement
    if(category == 'y'){
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns collection, not array. Collection hasn't array methods.

Comment: Thank you, fixed the answer

Comment: thank you @LGSon for the fix, the price of copy+paste failed me on this one :)

Answer (score 1):

Use "===" when you compare category to 'y'

Comment: If that work depends on which data type `category` has

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons

Answer (score 1):

You are doing several things wrong.

- use `===`, not `=`. The latter one is for assignment.
- add script after an element or wrap it in a function, otherwise it will execute before element exists on the site
- `getElementsByClassName` returns an array, not single element
- when you define variable in `if` statement it will not be available in `else` block
- is `category` defined somewhere?

```html
<div class="mydiv">
  <p><h1>Weather</h1></p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var category = 'n';
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mydiv")[0];
      x.style.display = (category === 'y') ? 'block' : 'none';
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: If `===` work depends on which data type `category` has

Comment: Yes, but `0 == ''` for example. Using `===` always is a good habit to have.

Comment: When using `===` the data type must match or else the comparison fails, using `==` will cast the value before compare

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons

Answer (score 0):

You had two issues. First, `getElementsByClassName()` returns an HTML Collection and instead of passing an index into that collection to correctly refer to the particular element in that collection that you want, you attempted to set the `style` property on the collection itself.

Next, your `if` statement uses `=` instead of `===`. The `=` sets a value, which (in an `if` statement) will always evaluate to `true`. You need comparison, so the `==` or `===` operators are needed.

Lastly, move your `script` tag so that it occurs after the HTML that it will use. Querying for an element prior to the element being parsed into memory will result in the element not being found.

```js
var x = document.querySelector(".mydiv");
var category = prompt("Enter 'y' or 'n'");
if(category === 'y'){
  x.style.display = 'block';
} else {
  x.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
  <h1>Weather</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct:

1. comparison, so use `==` instead of `=`
2. Need to access element by using index, like `getElementsByClassName("mydiv")[0]`; The reason is that `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, notice plural name in the api.
3. Also, need to take out var x outside of your if/else block. Otherwise else block will not have access to x.

See the sample:

```js
function test() {
        var category = 'n';
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mydiv")[0];
        if (category == 'y') {
            
            x.style.display = 'block';
        } else
            x.style.display = 'none';
    }
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-success" id="buttonCode" type="button" onclick="test()">test</button>
<div class="mydiv">
  <p><h1>Weather</h1></p>
</div>
```